# Does .NET have a check-and-set operator?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, parallel-processing, linearization

Where are the basic concurrency primitives in .Net?

Specifically I want to use a Check and Set operator.

Comment: Not sure what check and set is, but look into the `Interlocked` class. It has compare-and-exchange and similar operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the [Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) class in the `System.Threading` namespace. The `CompareExchange` is the method you're looking for.

It has the form `CompareExchange(target, value, comparand)` which in pseudo-code means `if(target==comparand) target=value;`.

There are also a load of other atomic methods on the `Interlocked` class that are useful, such as Increment, Decrement, Add and Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wx2c0dx.aspx).